# How to insert "Null" value in MySQL Database Cell if no Files are added?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that sends input data to corresponding field on MYSQL database.Right now I have it setup where any files that are uploaded are packaged in a zip and placed in the "uploads" folder while it sends to the database the file name/location. How do I make it where when the user uploads no files it sends to the database as NULL result in the corresponding database "file" cell and no zip file is sent to the "uploads" folder ? 
****UPDATE: OK I started with suggested answer but don't get "NULL" when no file is uploaded just the usual that I have written.I tried an if/else statement and it's the same. What am i doing wrong?**

> This what the array looks like when no file is uploaded: Array (
>   [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] =>
>   Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0]
>   => 0 ) )

The error field contains 4. i think this might the reason why its not working.I don't understand why this error field has this number. Any suggestions please?

PHP

```
<?php

$project = $_POST['project'];
$assignto = $_POST['assignto'];
$asdate = $_POST['asdate'];

$chdate = $_POST['chdate'];
$ddate = $_POST['ddate'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];


$asdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($asdate));
$chdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($chdate));
$ddate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ddate));

$timestamp = time();

if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) 
{
     $filesArray= $_FILES["files"];

 for ($num=0; $num<count($filesArray["name"]);$num++)
 {
     $fileName = $filesArray["name"][$num];
     $tempName= $filesArray["tmp_name"][$num];

     move_uploaded_file($tempName,"tmp/".$fileName);
 }
     $archiveName= $timestamp.".zip";
     $filesArrayNames= $_FILES["files"]["name"];


     $zipsDir= scandir ("uploads/");
     $error = false;
     foreach($zipsDir as $zipDirfile)
     {
         if($zipDirfile == $archiveName)
         {
             $error= true ;
             break;
         }
     }

        if ($error== false)
        {
            $tmpDir = scandir ("tmp/");
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $zip->open("uploads/".$archiveName, ZipArchive::CREATE);


             for ($num =0; $num<count($filesArray["name"]);$num++)
            {
            $fileName = $filesArray["name"][$num];
            foreach($tmpDir as $tmpDirfile)
            {
                    if($tmpDirfile == $fileName)
                    {
                    $zip->addFile("tmp/".$fileName);
                    echo " Adding: ".$fileName."<br/>"; 
                    }
            }
        }
        $zip->close();

        for ($num=0; $num<count($filesArray["name"]);$num++)
        { 
        $fileName = $filesArray["name"][$num];
            foreach($tmpDir as $tmpDirFile)
            {
                    if($tmpDirfile == $fileName)
                    {
                     unlink("tmp/".$fileName);
                    }

            }


          }
        }
        else 
        {                           
        echo "Name already exists";



 }

} if (!empty($filesArray)) {
$filepath = "NULL";
}else

{$filepath = addslashes("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.art.com/uploads/".$archiveName.""); }

print_r($filepath);

mysql_connect("tre.com","amadast","ufco1954") or die ('Error:' .mysql_error());
//database connection
    mysql_select_db("mediamanagement");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (`name`, `id_continent`, `lastvisit`, `cdate`, `ddate`, `file`,`notes`)
        VALUES ('".$project."', '".$assignto."','".$asdate."','".$chdate."','".$ddate."','".$filepath."','".$notes."')";
mysql_query($sql);


header('Location: edit-projects.html');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you create the $filepath variable, simply check whether you have files uploaded, and if you don't use "NULL" as the content.

For example:

```
$filepath = addslashes("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.amada-stage.com/uploads/".$archiveName.""); 
if (empty($filesArray)) {
    $filepath = "NULL";
}
```

You can do a similar thing to prevent the upload occuring:

Change

```
if ($error== false)
```

to

```
if ($error == false && !empty($filesArray))
```

BTW: I hope those aren't real database credentials in your mysql_connect line!

Comment: Ill try that  a bit. They are not real credentials. Thanks ,tho.

Comment: It didn't work. I added these suggestions but it posted the same. So basically it still sends the $filepath to the database instead of "NULL" when their are no files uploaded.